# sendBeacon not working in beforeunload handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, sendbeacon

I have the following useEffect hook in a React component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleUnload = function (event) {
        navigator.sendBeacon("https://webhook.site/8c3a42ce-c525-4a84-8783-f65175ed1297", JSON.stringify({ "foo": "bar" }));
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload);
    }

}, []);
```

Where the URL is just some test server that I've confirmed is working using Postman. However when I close the browser, the request is not received.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why does this not work?
2. Is there any way to send an array of javascript objects with sendBeacon?

Many thanks

Comment: I am having same issue with similar code in beforeunlaod event, but able to see it working if i run in debug mode. If i dont use debug mode req isnt recieved.

Comment: @Alex  did you get this working?